# Android java - dynamically add ImageViews in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android

i would like to add to a LinearLayout some imageViews dynamically in my app.
My following code doesn't show errors and prints what it is supposed to on logcat each time an ImageView is added from java code.

My problem is that when i run the app the images don't appear on screen....any idea where i am doing wrong ?

thanks a lot.

public class MesListesFragment extends Fragment {

```
private RecyclerView mes_listes_recyclerView;
private ArrayList<ListItem> liste_items;
private LinearLayout list_card_categories;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mes_listes_fragment, container, false);
    View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, container, false);

    mes_listes_recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.mes_listes_recyclerView);
    list_card_categories = view2.findViewById(R.id.list_card_recyclerView);

    liste_items = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
        liste_items.add(new ListItem("Liste des ploucs", "18 Août 198" + i));
    }

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mes_listes_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mes_listes_recyclerView.setAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(getContext(), liste_items));

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        ImageView image = new ImageView(getContext());
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.user);
        list_card_categories.addView(image);
        Log.d("view created", "...");
    }
    return view;
}
```

}

Here is the xml, the file's called list_item.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_card_first_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_card_textView_nom_liste"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Nom de la liste"></TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_card_textView_date_liste"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Date liste"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>


            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/list_card_recyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_card_second_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/list_card_first_container"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/list_card_button_editer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:background="@color/bleu_fb"
                android:text="@string/editer"></Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/list_card_button_supprimer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:text="@string/supprimer"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Can you share the XML code for the same?

Comment: Of course here it is :

Comment: Is this a recycler view item?

Comment: No, first i tried with recyclerView but i thought that a simple LinearLayout should be enough to display it. Sorry about layout's ids i know that this is confusing.....I'll handle it when functionalities will work.

Comment: So you are setting all your code in view2?

Comment: Sorry i'm beggining so I'm not sure about what to answer, but in my code, view represents the fragment that contains the list and view2 represents the layout of each list item.
I thought I had to create the view2 to retrieve list_card_recyclerView which is the LinearLayout displaying a horizontal list of ImageViews.

Comment: You can follow this simple tutorial to implement RecyclerView in android https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview

Comment: ok thank you for the help

Comment: Yes sure. Anytime man